# Is there a version of Harvey in which Harvey becomes visible in the final scene?

Tags: alternate-version, harvey

I recall seeing a version of [**Harvey**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_(film)#Remakes) on TV in the late 1970s or early 1980s with James Stewart walking up the hill in the final scene and Harvey appears walking beside him. I'm fairly certain it was in black and white.

There are numerous remakes plus several releases on VHS, DVD and a Blu-ray. Perhaps one of them has Harvey appear at the end.

I recently bought a DVD version but Harvey did not appear walking up the hill.

I also found a VHS tape but unfortunately the tape was damaged towards the end.

Comment: Welcome to the community, check this page at [Identify-This-X Questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and try to add as much information as you can.

But what are you asking for ? to identify a movie ? Are you talking about different version of a movie and which one ? Please enlight us.

Comment: I seem to recall this too. Perhaps it was a more modern spoof or homage.

Comment: I could swear as a child there was a version as they went over the hill, a giant white rabbit was seen. So you are not the only one.

Comment: Hi @M.Polo There are several remakes of Harvey including a 1972 TV movie also starring James Stewart. I was wondering if anyone has seen a movie with the titular pooka named Harvey in which he is visible at the end (perhaps starring James Stewart)? I'm fairly certain it was in black and white. I saw it on TV in the late 1970s or 1980s. Also, I wasn't sure if it was a different version, perhaps remastered for an anniversary, or one of the remakes.

Comment: The first time I saw Harvey it was on television a long time ago. Has to be decades ago. One of the major things I remembered about the movie was Jimmy Stewart and the rabbit walking close together side by side at the very end. I could only see the back of Harvey. I have not seen that version since.

Comment: As I remember the movie of 1950 (which I saw in 2004), it ends with a shot of a door moved by an unseen force; that's the only explicit hint that the rabbit might be real.

Comment: I saw the movie on TV in the mid 70s. I definitely remember seeing the backside of Harvey walking with Stewart at the end. I recently showed a version of the film to my kids but was disappointed that it didn't show anything at the end - couldn't believe it. My wife made a remark about it also.

Answer (score 5):

No such version of the **1950** original screen version exists.

> Mary Chase [the writer] had the idea that film audiences should actually see Harvey at the end of the film because she "didn't want anybody to go out of the theater thinking Elwood is just a lush. He believes in Harvey...and I think the audience ought to believe in Harvey, too."
>
> The studio reportedly considered this and experimented with how to show him to the audience, including his appearance in silhouette, and even by attaching a rabbit tail to the taxi driver at the film's conclusion. **In the end, however, the studio won out and wisely decided NOT to ruin the illusion.**
>
> Only once had a giant rabbit actually appeared on stage in the play of Harvey, and the results were disastrous. Theatrical Producer Brock Pemberton recalled in a 1945 interview that at that performance in Boston, "a chill descended on the gathering, which never quite thawed out afterwards."
>
> <sup>[TCM.com](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/19347/Harvey/articles.html)</sup>

As far as I can tell, Harvey only appears in a portrait painting:

[[image]]

---

The movie was [remade for TV in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_(1996_film)) but I apparently Harvey does not actually appear in that version either.

The ending scene in the 1996 differs from the 1950 original.